# Set Expiration to Redis Command request

Tags: vert.x

How to set the expiration within a Request object?

I have

```java
Request r = Request.cmd(Command.SET).arg("mykey").arg("myvalue");
```

How to set the expiration of that key? I don't really understand the purpose of the `getDelegate()` method.

I don't want to write an other Request command like that :

```java
Request expire = Request.cmd(Command.EXPIRE).arg("mykey").arg(20);
```

I want to do it in only one Request object.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vert.x Redis Client API idea is to be as close to original REDIS commands as possible. This is because the Vertx.X Redis interfaces are directly generated from result of [COMMAND](https://redis.io/commands/command/)

In regards to this there are 2 possible ways to achieve this.

1. Using [SET](https://redis.io/commands/set/) command with additional EX parameter. In this case your command will look something like this:

```java
Request.cmd(Command.SET).arg("mykey").arg("myvalue").arg("EX").arg("15")
```

2. Using [SETEX](https://redis.io/commands/setex/) command. In this case your command will look something like this:

```java
Request.cmd(Command.SETEX).arg("mykey").arg("15").arg("myvalue")
```

Best way to use Vert.x Redis Client API is to always check how each command is used via [REDIS COMMANDS](https://redis.io/commands/) and transfer that 1:1 to Vert.X API.

Comment: Why does Redis not support the EX parameter for HSET like it does for SET ? It is constraining to have to make a second EXPIRE command

Comment: @bdeweer because the [hset](https://redis.io/commands/hset/) command doesn't support such opeartion itself.